# choose how many numbers to print after dot using a variable

Tags: c, printf, double

Lets say for example I want to print result 3 numbers after the dot.

I can just use the following code:

```
  printf("%.3f",result);
```

I want to use it using the variable "precision" instead of writing 3

```
  printf("%.precisionf");
```

how do i do that correctly

Comment: until a recent update in the C language, you could do: `printf( "%."precision"f" );`  Now need to use something like `sprintf()` to generate the 'format string' and then use that format string (a char array) in the call to `printf()`.  This results in a warning about 'security' but will get the job done.

Comment: @user3629249: Hasn't `.*` been around since the late 1970s?

Comment: @Bathsheba,  Please post an example of what your trying to say

Comment: @user3629249: I did better than that in that I answered ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the somewhat forgotten `".*"` format:

```
printf("%.*f", precision, result);
```

where `precision` is an `int`. Full program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    double result = 1.234567;
    int precision = 3;
    printf("%.*f", precision, result);
}
```

See https://ideone.com/WFimaU

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with sprintf to create the format string in the following way:

```
char tmp[10];
sprintf(tmp,"%%.%df",precision);
printf(tmp, result);
```

Simple, don't?